# OpenCSV parsing does not show special character

Tags: java, swing, jtable, opencsv

I am trying to load a .csv file in jTable. In notepad the file shows OK but in jTable some characters like "£", "$" becomes a box.

```
private void parseUsingOpenCSV(String filename){

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) empTbl.getModel();
int rows = model.getRowCount();
if (rows>0){
for(int i=0 ; i<rows; i++)
{model.removeRow(0);}
}   

    try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String [] nextLine;
        int rowNumber = 0;

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            rowNumber++;
                model.addRow(new Object[]{nextLine[0], nextLine[1], nextLine[2], nextLine[3], nextLine[4], nextLine[5], nextLine[6], nextLine[7]});
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: never, ever, use the class "FileReader"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Match the encoding of your file to that used by the `InputStreamReader`, for example if your file is ISO-8859-1, you can use

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

---

UTF-8 requires 2 bytes to display a character whereas ISO-8859-1 only required 1. If an ISO-8859-1 encoded file is read using UTF-8, then characters such as `£` will not display correctly if displayed with the latter.

Read: [A Rough Guide to Character Encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.ie/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html)

Comment: Your file may have a different encoding, try with ISO-8859-1. See update

Comment: ISO-8859-1 works fine. "UTF-8" does not. But the reason is still unknown. Anyway, Thanks Reimeus.